# Compilation error with c++11 thread

Tags: multithreading, templates, c++11

I try to understand why my code gives a compilation error. I've made a minimal example that keep same behaviour / architecture and error than the code in my project. The goal is to made a parallel evaluation of object in a vector.

```
template < class InputIterator, class OutputIterator >
void evaluate( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator outfirst ) {
    while( first != last ) {
        *outfirst++ = (*first++) / 2 ; // only for the example
    }
}

template < int num_t = 4 >
struct ParallelEvaluator {

    template< typename InputContainer , typename OutputContainer >
    static void eval(InputContainer const & src, OutputContainer & dst) {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads ;
        auto bg = src.begin() ;
        auto bg_r = dst.begin() ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_t ; i++ ) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(evaluate<typename InputContainer::iterator,typename OutputContainer::iterator>
                                          ,bg,bg+4,bg_r)) ;
            bg = bg+4 ;
            bg_r = bg_r + 4 ;
        }
        std::for_each(threads.begin(),threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> t = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} ;
    std::vector<int> v(16) ;

    ParallelEvaluator<4>::eval(t,v) ;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this code I get the following error :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >))(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>'
```

I saw that kind of error occurs when reference are using in the thread callback but it is not the case here.

Does somebody know why this error occurs ? Do I need a specific syntax to use template and co ?

Thanks

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: @Angew the line in the loop for `threads.push_back(...)`

Comment: Interesting problem. I've looked at the full error on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3doQTx) and it seems the standard library is incapable of realising that `evaluate<:::>` is a function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `bg` is not `std::vector<int>::iterator`, it is `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` since `src` is a `const&`. Be lazy and let the compiler deduce the correct types with `decltype`.  (Also, you could avoid some memory allocations by using `std::array<std::thread,num_t>` instead of `std::vector<std::thread>`.):

```
template< typename InputContainer , typename OutputContainer >
static void eval(InputContainer const & src, OutputContainer & dst) {
    std::array<std::thread, num_t> threads ;
    auto bg = src.begin() ;
    auto bg_r = dst.begin() ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_t ; i++ ) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(evaluate<decltype(bg),decltype(bg_r)>
                                 ,bg,bg+4,bg_r)) ;
        bg = bg+4 ;
        bg_r = bg_r + 4 ;
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(),threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
}
```

If you don't find lambdas offensive, `threads[i] = std::thread([=]{ evaluate(bg,bg+4,bg_r); });` does the same thing with a bit less syntax.

Comment: I just realised the same from the full error message, you beat me to writing it down. Have a +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your types do not match -- you are passing `const_iterator`s and explicitly expecting `iterator`s, because you got the type you are expecting wrong, because `template` functions are annoying to pass around.

To fix this wrap your `template` funxtions you want to pass around into perfect forwarding override set functors:

```
struct evaluate_t { template<class...Args> void operator()(Args&&...args)const{
  evaluate( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}};
static evaluate_t evaluate_overrides;
```

then pass `evaluate_overrides` to `std::thread` instead of `evaluate<blah,blah>`.  Which override to use is now deferred to the point where it is called, instead of where you pass it in.